# How should I set a global variable in kivy Python?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

My application is simple, the ScreenTwo is showing a form 'Parametreur' with various options to be entered.
What I'm trying to do is to set a 'save' button at the end of this form that will register into a list called 'resultat' all the options furfilled so far leaving '0' in the empty inputs.
The global variable 'resultat' would look like this ['blabla','15/06/2018','31/12/1999','6'].

#### File.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, WipeTransition
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file("HadrianRunningApp.kv")

class ScreenMenu(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class Parametreur(FloatLayout):
    def build(self):
        pass

    def submit_input(self):
        # Get the student name from the TextInputs
        label_name = self.label_text_input.text
        resultat.insert(0,label_name)

    def submit_input2(self):
        date_debut_name = self.date_debut_input.text
        resultat.insert(1,date_debut_name)

    def submit_input3(self):
        date_fin_name = self.date_fin_input.text
        resultat.insert(2,date_fin_name)

    def submit_input4(self):
        var_duree_estimation = self.duree_estimation_input.text
        resultat.insert(3,var_duree_estimation)

    def save_input(self):
        print(resultat)

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    screen_menu = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_two = ObjectProperty(None)

class ScreensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        m = Manager(transition=WipeTransition())
        return m

if __name__=='__main__':
    ScreensApp().run()
```

#### The Kivy file .kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<ScreenMenu>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size: root.size
        padding: "20dp"
        Button:
            text: "go to Screen 1"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'
        Button:
            text: "go to Screen 2"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Parametreur'

<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 20
        padding: 20
        Button:
            text: "go to Screen 2"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Parametreur'
        Button:
            text: "go to Menu"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen0'
<ScreenTwo>:
    Parametreur

<Parametreur>:
    label_text_input: label_text
    date_debut_input: date_debut
    date_fin_input: date_fin
    duree_estimation_input: duree_estimation
    resultat: resultat

    RelativeLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: (1., 0.11)
            pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'center_y': 0.91}
            padding: 6
            spacing: "4dp"
            cols:2
            rows:1
            Button:
                text: "go to Screen 1"
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'
            Button:
                text: "go to Menu"
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen0'
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: (1., 0.8)
            pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'center_y': 0.45}
            padding: "7dp"
            spacing: 5
            cols:2
            rows:7
            Button:
                text: "Liste Actif"
            Label:
                text: " "
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: "Date du début"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    Button:
                        text: "Submit"
                        on_press: root.submit_input2()
                    TextInput:
                        id: date_debut
                        text: 'dd/mm/YYYY'          
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: "Date de fin"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    Button:
                        text: "Submit"
                        on_press: root.submit_input3()
                    TextInput:
                        id: date_fin
                        text: 'dd/mm/YYYY'
            Label:
                text: "Pourcentage de séparation \n de la base (validation/test)"
            Button:
                text: "Open to Close"
            Button:
                text: "Close to Close"
            Button:
                text: "les 3 (6 en tout) frontières des VSs"
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: "Durée pour la réestimation \n des modèles (en jours)"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    Button:
                        text: "Submit"
                        on_press: root.submit_input4()
                    TextInput:
                        id: duree_estimation
                        text: 'dd/mm/YYYY'
            Label:
                text: "variable selection NMF/Entropy"
            Label:
                text: "Kernel/damiers/buntcher/\n neurone/XGBoost/Gradient boosting"

            # We create the widgets
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: "0dp"
                Label:
                    id: label_text
                    text: "0"
                    font_size: "30dp"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    spacing: "3dp"
                    Button:
                        text: "Add"
                        on_release: label_text.text = str(int(label_text.text) + 1)
                    Button:
                        text: "Subtract"
                        on_release: label_text.text = str(int(label_text.text) - 1)
                Button:
                    text: "Submit"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    on_press: root.submit_input()
            BoxLayout:
                padding: "2dp"
                spacing: "2dp"
                size_hint: (1., 0.50)
                pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'center_y': 0.09}
                Button:
                    id: resultat
                    text:"Save"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    on_press: root.save_input()

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    screen_menu: screen_menu
    screen_one: screen_one
    screen_two: screen_two


    ScreenMenu:
        id: screen_menu
        name: 'screen0'
        manager: screen_manager 

    ScreenOne:
        id: screen_one
        name: 'screen1'
        manager: screen_manager 

    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two
        name: 'Parametreur'
        manager: screen_manager
```

#### Where and How should I set my global variable 'resultat' (which is a list)?

I've solved my problem but I still don't understand how does it work. Setting a variable is Kivy doesn't need to set it in the Python code. But how do Kivy and Python know about its type? Right now, it works as a list without me defining it such as (I intended it to be a list anyway).

#### How could I set a variable as tuple for example?

Comment: its not clear what you are asking... you clearly link some python to your screen kv stuff with your button press for example ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143199/create-global-variable-in-kivy

Comment: Not really, I have already read the link you are providing and it doesn't answer the question. 
Maybe I should define my class 'Parametreur()' as a subclass of a new class 'save()' to include all the buttons within this logic?
It sounds overly complicated for such a basic need.